# Ошибка CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: Скрин ошибки]Попытался сделать что-бы камера следила за персонажем по X и Y но при этом была на 2.49 выше центра персонажа.

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class CamMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float camY = player.transform.position.y+2.49;
        transform.position = new Vector2 (player.transform.position.x, camY);
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку: error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
Буду благодарен каждой попытке помочь.

Comment: `float camY = (float) (player.transform.position.y+2.49);`?

Comment: Или `double camY` =) И в конструктор уже (float) camY слать) Или 2.49f

Comment: `2.49f` - сделайте литерал типа `float`

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, помогло, ты лучший.

Comment: [Литерал без суффикса или с суффиксом d или D имеет тип double.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

Comment: "Да знаю вопрос лёгкий, но я только начал изучать C#" — зачем, зачем, Вы пишете это в заголовке вопроса?

Answer (score 2):

добавьте f для литерала 2.49

```
float camY = player.transform.position.y+2.49f;
```